# How change collectionView size or layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I have UITableView cell and i had nested UICollectionView. How change the height of the UICollectionView ?

Comment: Please ask question more detailed , provide what you have tried, what is exact output you want, and what you are getting , provide image screen shot if possible

Comment: I want create a nested uicollectionview at uitableviewcell.My problem is the layout of uicollectionview .i need uicollectionview set equals size width and height like uitableviewcell.

Comment: Can you share the expected output and the one you are getting to get more clarity on the issue.

Comment: I had create this example https://codedump.io/share/Nzq7C1ZTakIk/1/ios-8-swift---tableview-with-embedded-collectionview but i dont want gravity horizontal ,i need elements to look like gridview .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code
change the frame size according to your need

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width, collectionView.frame.size.height);
}
```

It works for me and i hope it works for you too :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer .The code patse inside uitablecell class?

Comment: you can use this code with UICollectionView delegate methods. and change it according to your need